# Ubuntu one on samsung galaxi mini2: i can see my folders but not the files inside!

Tags: samsung

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and I use Ubuntu one for my back ups and as cloud...I have my music there and my photos out of any back up folder.
I just bought a smartphone Samsung Galaxy mini2 and I downloaded the ubuntu one app to be able to have my music on this device....the problem is that when i try to access my files, i can see all the folders and subfolders but when i open them it says that they are empty! all of them! I can see the folders, but not the files inside!
what's up? 
Thank you,
Michela

Comment: are you connected via wifi ? Please check in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Galaxy SII...this previous post helped:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1881883

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.